# Why does my pyspark just hang as ACCEPTED in yarn when I launch it?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I just spun up a new `AWS` instance in `Linux`.  And, I installed `pyspark` on it.  It has `spark 1.6`.

I'm running `pyspark` with `yarn`.  When I do the command `pyspark` in the terminal, it launches initially, but then I get the message:

```
dd/mm/YY HH:MM:SS INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX (state: ACCEPTED)
```

.....and then this just continues for forever.

So, I checked `yarn`to see if anything else was running:

```
yarn application -list
```

And ONLY shows my application running.  How do I open up the `pyspark` shell and get my application to start rather than just being `ACCEPTED`?

Answer (score 4):

Can you try to run spark-shell and see if that goes into running state or not?

This happens when yarn doesn't have requested resources from it.

Example: Lets say yarn has 5gb of free memory available and you are requesting 10gb. Your job would be stuck in Accepted phase till it gets the requested memory.

Try running your job with below config:

```
pyspark --total-executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 1G
```

Comment: okay.  how would I know how much free memory there is?  And how do I know how much memory I'm requesting?

Comment: have you used dr.who or cloudera manager or ambari kind of tool? from there you can check how much free memory there is.

can you try to run : spark-shell --master local and confirm if that went through or not?

Comment: No, only using the command line. yes `spark-shell --master local` goes through and works correctly.  What does this tell us?

Comment: This tells us that there is no problem with the spark installation as it is able to run in local mode.

What happens when you do just spark-shell ?

Comment: when i do just `spark-shell` it opens up a `scala` shell, as expected right?

Comment: @Hunle Yes.
Try running pyspark with below configuration.

 pyspark --total-executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 1G

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Grover answer, you can set [spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) and [yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.3/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/preemption.html) to True to get your job started asap.

Comment: I actually have `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` already set to "true" in my `spark-defaults.conf` file. 

I do not know where to set `yarn.scheduler .fair.preemption` - is that a property of `yarn-site.xml` or `spark-defaults.conf` or neither?

I am actually using a fair scheduler, so it might make sense to add some configuration around that.

Comment: you should add the property to your yarn-site.yml `<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>`. For advanced configuration (groups, group priority) I recommend Cloudera blog post [1](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/) &[2](https://blog.cloudera.com/page/1/?s=preemption)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is with resources or queues.

Please set all this options in `yarn-site.xml` to have enough resources on your cluster:
 `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`, `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores`, `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`

Also you might hit a bug/problem with queues, which can be resolved by setting `queueMaxAMShareDefault` to `-1.0` in `fair-scheduler.xml`(on the node with Resource Manager) if you use fair scheduler, and restart Resource Manager.